# Custom XBL component for submitting form

Tags: orbeon

I'm trying to implement a custom xbl component to submit the form to an external service, perform validation and handle the validation results. The version of orbeon is 4.4-CE deployed on JBoss 7.1.1.Final with MySQL persistence layer.

```
<xbl:binding element="fr|custom-submit" id="fr-custom-submit" xxbl:mode="lhha binding value">
    <xbl:implementation>
        <xf:model id="custom-submit-model">
            <xf:instance id="validation-res">
                <dummy/>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- External validation submission -->
            <xf:submission id="form-submission" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')"
                action="http://localhost:8080/webapp/services/task/submitData" method="post"
                replace="instance" instance="validation-res">
                <xf:delete ev:event="xforms-submit" ref="//@v:*"/>
                <xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit-done">
                    <!-- Insert external validation results when done -->
                    <xf:insert ref="." origin="instance('validation-res')/v:data/*"/>

                    <!-- Handle the valid/invalid result -->
                </xf:action>
            </xf:submission>

        </xf:model>
    </xbl:implementation>
    <xbl:template>
        <fr:button ref="xxf:binding('fr-custom-submit')">
            <xf:label>
                <xh:img src="/apps/fr/style/images/silk/disk.png"/>
                <xh:span>Custom save</xh:span>
            </xf:label>
            <xf:send ev:event="DOMActivate" submission="form-submission"/>
        </fr:button>

    </xbl:template>
</xbl:binding>
```

Upon submitting the form the following exception occurs in the log files:

```
Empty single-node binding on xf:submission for submission id: form-submission                                         |
```

I cannot figure out, what the exception means and if the cause of the problem is the strong encapsulation as described [here](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components-guide#TOC-Encapsulation).

Is it in general possible to write a custom xbl component for submitting a form? How can I overcome the above mentioned problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed an issue related to encapsulation, and using `xxf:instance()` allows you to break the encapsulation. So in your case, the submission would do:

```
ref="xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')"
```